# SQL: UPDATE many-to-many's intermediate table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update, many-to-many

I have table *A* and table *B*. Relation between them done using intermediate table *AB*, which stores ID's from both.

```
Table A 

ID integer
Value varchar(MAX)

Table B 

ID integer
Value varchar(MAX)

Table AB 

AID integer
BID integer
```

I can select needed data with `JOIN`'s, but how to write data into `AB`? 
I mean if I'll get `AID` and list of `integer`'s (done as custom type *Array_Integer* `table(ID integer)`) , which is `BID`, how to update relations in `AB` with a received list of `BID`'s?
I can do a lot of dirty and manually work, but I'm looking for a more true way.

UPD: check schema on pastebin — http://pastebin.com/BeKm2h3F

Comment: you can use MERGE Statement to manage (Insert/Update/Delete based on a list) child or mapping table

Comment: It'll be good, if you'll explain this.

Comment: In what format do you get this lists?

Comment: As a custom type, `table(ID integer)`.

Comment: Create some sample data to test and expected output

Comment: Please try this. 

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f3bff0/1

Comment: Same on pastebin. 

http://pastebin.com/BeKm2h3F

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correct, this query should be what you need.

```
INSERT INTO AB
SELECT * FROM 
(
    -- Here you write your AID value instead of 1
    SELECT 1 AS AID
) AS a1
CROSS JOIN 
(
    -- Query that returns list if id's from table B
    SELECT ID AS BID FROM B WHERE ID < 5
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can update the TableAB as follows :

```
declare @Aid int
declare @Bid int

insert into TableA(value)
select 'abcd'
set @Aid = ident_currect('TableA')

insert into TableB(value)
select 'xyz'
set @Bid = ident_currect('TableB')

insert into TableAB  -- This will update your junction table
select @Aid,@Bid
```

I am assuming that your tableA and TableB have identity columns. You can also use scope_identity() instead of ident_currect()